# Playing roulette using martingale

Tags: probability, random-variables, game-theory, martingales, gambling

A player with unlimited money decides to play roulette. He bets $1$ on red, if he loses, he bets $2$, if he loses again he bets $4$ and so on till he wins. Prove that he is guaranteed to make a profit.

I know this is the theory of martingale and I looked for proof online but everything I found was way more complex than what's needed here. Isn't there a formula to prove that after unlimited tries the probability of never winning is $0$?

I understand why it works but I'm having a hard time explaining it using mathematics. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that the player loses all of the first $n$ spins?  What happens to this as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: well i suppose it is $(\frac{19}{37})^n$ and since $n\rightarrow \infty$ then it is $0$ but how do i prove the expected value or in other word that he is guranteed to make a profit?

Comment: If he ever wins then he makes a profit.  You have just shown he wins with probability 1 (this may or may not be the same as a "guarantee" depending on your point of view).  (Note that rigorously proving that the probability of the limit equals the limit of the probabilities requires a rigorous definition of what "probability" means, which in turn requires learning measure theory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that the probability $p$ of winning a given spin is
$$p=0.5$$
and then the probability of losing $q$ on a given hand is
$$q=1-p=0.5$$

With the martingale betting system, one win will yield a net profit because you always bet more than you've lost. The probability you will not win at least once after $n$ spins is
$$q^{n}=0.5^n$$

The limit of this expression as $n\to\infty$ then represents the probability that you will never win. The limit is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}0.5^n = 0$$

Therefore the roulette player will [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) win at least once, yielding a net profit.